# Get ICMP packet payload

Tags: ping, icmp

I know, that I can send a custom payload with `-p` param in hex format, like `ping -p DEADBEAF 8.8.8.8`
Just curious, does the server could answer with payload too? If yes, how can I show it in terminal?

And moreover, can I implement it on my server, in python for example? So I could answer on ping with 16bytes msgs, that would be funny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently wondered what gets sent in a ping on Windows and this is what I got:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3N2koAvLeyJRnNjRDBpQ2o4dUE/view

The system sends an incomplete Latin alphabet (why no x, y and z?) and a Linux router responds with the same value.

You can view what gets sent with a network sniffer (or analyzer to make it sound less threatening) like tcpdump.

I assume you have to return the same value the client sends but I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing the response doesn't require the same data.

Comment: So, it's possible, great